# SpriteSheet Class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite-sheet

I want to do my own SpriteSheet Class for ActionScript 3.

The purpose of this class would be a replacement for the MovieClip class, the only difference is that the frames will come from a SpriteSheet. Many of my classes will extend from this class.

My problem is: What if I had a sub-class, for example Ball, that uses the same SpriteSheet for all instances of Ball and i would like to re-use that SpriteSheet to use in all balls to save a lot of memory.

Comment: [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) is a framework which provides similar functionalities to what you are trying to accomplish. You may find it quite useful in 2D game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the same SpriteSheet for all instances of Ball, your Ball class shouldn't extend from SpriteSheet class. The base class should contain a variable of SpriteSheet type, and be initialized when the class is created.

So you need a singleton class to save all the SpriteSheet classes with a dictionary, the key of dictionary may like "Ball", "MAN_RUN".The SpriteSheet class will contain a list of BitmapData.

The code may like this

```
public class Animation {

    private var _spriteSheet:SpriteSheet;

    public function Animation(key:String)
    {
        spriteSheet = SpriteSheetMgr.instance.getSpriteSheet(key);
    }
}

private var ball:Ball = new Ball("Ball");
```